# Why did Sue want to go back to Phillotson?

Tags: character-analysis, thomas-hardy, jude-the-obscure

In the novel *Jude the Obscure* by Thomas Hardy, Sue was broken after the death of her children. She went to their graves and wept even on the insistence of Jude to go back to the lodge. Jude was broken too, but he understood that he had to care for Sue.

However, after these events Jude thought that he could now live with Sue with the sorrow of his and her dead children but Sue had some other moral and religious principles in her mind. She decided to leave Jude [to die?] and to have a full marital relation with Phillotson.

My question is what were her thoughts behind leaving Jude and living with Phillotson again? Did she think that that way will provide her some consolation?